# Returning the new string in the method

Tags: c#

I'm newbie to c#, So i tried the below program, which will change the case of the first character of the string

```
public class StringBuilder
    {
        public static string ChangeFirstLetterCase(string inputdata)
        {
            if(inputdata.Length > 0)
            {
                char[] charArray = inputdata.ToCharArray();
                charArray[0] = char.IsUpper(charArray[0]) ? 
                    char.ToLower(charArray[0]) : char.ToUpper(charArray[0]);
                //return new string(charArray);
                return charArray.ToString();
            }
            return inputdata;
        }
    }
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = StringBuilder.ChangeFirstLetterCase("vishnu");
            Console.WriteLine(a);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Since the return type of this method `ChangeFirstLetterCase()` is a string. So I'm just doing the conversion like below

```
`return charArray.ToString();`
```

So in the method call it is returning the `System.Char[]`

Alternatively I tried the below one as well

```
`return new string(charArray);`
```

So this is returning the value as expected

```
Argument to the method - "vishnu"
Return value - "Vishnu"
```

So my question here is

1. Since the return type of the method is string, what's wrong with below conversion?

   `return charArray.ToString();`
2. How do we know when to return as new string?.

   `return new string(charArray);`

Please provide me some example

Comment: What's the question here? You seem to know how to convert char array to string by `new string(charArray)`.

Comment: @sriram - I mentioned my que..What didn't u understand from there?

Comment: I'm wondering why your class's name is `StringBuilder` when there is an existing `StringBuilder` class in `System.Text`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @maniak - Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 3):

If you return the char array as a String, it will return you the name of the object `System.Char[]`. This is because the ToString method of char arrays does not build the characters of the array into a usable string, but simply makes a String that states the type of object.

However, if you use `new String(char[])`, this will read the contents of the char array to build a string out of whatever characters are in the char array. So, you will want to use `new String(char[])` for most of your String building, I cannot think of any real uses for using the `ToString()` on a char array.

So, for your example, you should use `return new String(charArray);` instead of `return charArray.ToString();`.

Answer (score 1):

`charArray.ToString();` returns the type name because it's implemented that way, for getting string back from a character array you will always have to use `String` class constructor.

`ToString` method for `char[]` is not implemented in a way to return the character array back as a string literal, so use `String` constructor as you did in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

You could return:

```
if(inputData[0].IsLower())
   return string.Concat(inputData[0].ToUpper(), inputData.Substring(1));  
else 
   return string.Concat(inputData[0].ToLower(), inputData.Substring(1));
```

Your value would already be a usable string and wouldn't need to have a char[].

I'm not really sure what you gain from converting the string to a char array to being with.